# Finding the acceleration equation given the position equation

Tags: calculus

On a flat playground, choose a Cartesian $Oxy$ coordinate system (in
unit of meters). A child running at a constant velocity $V = 1$ m/s around a heart-shaped path satisfies the following order-6 algebraic equation: $$(x^2+y^2-10^2)^3 - 10x^2y^3=0.$$ When the child is at the position $(x,y)=(10,0)$, what is the magnitude of their acceleration?

---

My attempts:

I tried taking the derivative of this equation twice (with respect to time):
$$2x\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)\ +\ 2y\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)=10^{\frac{1}{3}}\left[\left(\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}\right)\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)\left(y\right)+\left(x^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\right] \qquad \text{first derivative}.$$

$$2\left[\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)+\left(x\right)\left(\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}}\right)\right]\ +\ 2\left[\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)+\left(y\right)\left(\frac{d^{2}y}{dt^{2}}\right)\right]=10^{\frac{1}{3}}\left[\right] \qquad \text{second derivative}.$$

After this, I noted that the acceleration is $$\sqrt{(\frac{d^2x}{dt^2})^2 + (\frac{d^2y}{dt^2})^2}.$$ But I'm not sure how to find this from the above equation.

Can someone help?

Comment: Did you consider using v^2=1 and plucking in x=10 and y=0

Comment: @user7777777 The direction changes, so there is an acceleration.

Comment: @trula I'm not sure what you mean. Can you post an answer so I can understand better?

Comment: Can someone help?

Comment: Your approach (2nd derivatives) will work. From the original equation, the first derivative, the fact $\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2=1$, and the given coordinates, you can work out the components of the velocity; then you can plug in to the second derivative to work out the acceleration components.

Comment: Sorry, I missed an equation - you can also differentiate $\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2=1$ wrt $t$.

Comment: ***Don't*** vandalize posts, even if  they are your own.

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answer uses a different method, I'll post what I was describing in the comments. The idea is to use implicit differentiation on both the equation of the curve and the speed condition to get equations in $x,\dot{x},\ddot{x},y,\dot{y},\ddot{y}$, then solve these simultaneously for the particular point $(10,0)$.

For the curve, start with a slightly rearranged version of the original equation:
$$x^2+y^2-100=10^{\frac13} x^\frac23 y$$

Differentiate with respect to $t$:
$$2\dot{x}x+2\dot{y}y=10^{\frac13} \left[\frac23 \dot{x} x^{-\frac13} y+ x^\frac23 \dot{y}\right] \tag{1}$$

And again:
$$2\dot{x}^2+2\dot{y}^2+2\ddot{x} x+2\ddot{y} y=10^{\frac13} \left[-\frac29  \dot{x}^2 x^{-\frac43} y + \frac43 \ddot{x} x^{-\frac13} y+x^\frac23 \ddot{y} \right] \tag{2}$$

The given condition on the runner's speed is
$$\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2=1 \tag{3}$$

We can also differentiate this to get
$$\ddot{x}\dot{x}+\ddot{y}\dot{y}=0 \tag{4}$$

(we need this additional step to have enough equations for our unknowns).

---

Now, at $(10,0)$, we have $x=10$ and $y=0$. Substituting into equation $(1)$ gives
$$20\dot{x}=10\dot{y} \tag{1a}$$

and with equation $(3)$ we can work out $\dot{x}=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt5}$ and $\dot{y}=\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt5}$, where the signs are the same (after all, we don't know which way round the heart the child is running; let's assume they're both positive as we get the same answer either way).

These values can then be substituted into equations $(2)$ and $(4)$ to get
$$\ddot{x}=-\frac{22}{375},\quad \ddot{y}=\frac{11}{375}$$

so that the magnitude of the acceleration at $(10,0)$ is $\boxed{\frac{11}{75\sqrt5}}$.

Comment: By the way, what happens if we *don't* rearrange the curve's equation before differentiating?